# Javascript `?.` operator: why is `not defined` not treated as `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, undefined

Assuming `w` has not been previously defined, the following JS code gives `ReferenceError: w is not defined`:

```
w?.y;
```

whereas this code simply returns `undefined`:

```
let w; w?.y;
```

Why does the `?.` operator not treat `not defined` as `undefined`?

Comment: When in doubt, read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Try `window.w?.y`.

Comment: when in doubt "if (typeof w !== 'undefined') ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> Optional chaining cannot be used on a ***non-declared*** root object, but can be used with an undefined root object.

which means you have to declare the **root object**, in this case, it's `w`

Answer (score 1):

The difference is between trying to access a (potentially) non-existent **variable** vs a (potentially) non-existent **property**.

From MDN:

On [reference errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError):

> The `ReferenceError` object represents an error when a variable that doesn't exist (or hasn't yet been initialized) in the current scope is referenced.

This is the case in your first example:

```js
const value = w?.y;
//            ^ ReferenceError occurs here
console.log(value);
```

On [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

> The `?.` operator is like the `.` chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) ([`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null) or [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`.

This is the case in your second example:

```js
let w;
const value = w?.y;
//            ^ Reference exists (but it is undefined)
console.log(value);
```

Comment: `let w; w?.y;` is specifically **not** trying to access a non-existent property.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73752649/javascript-operator-why-is-not-defined-not-treated-as-undefined/73752716#comment130234303_73752716) @connexo Thanks for the feedback. Apparently I needed to clarify by adding the adverb _potentially_.

Comment: None of the two cases is trying to access a non-existent property, so why are you mentioning it?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73752649/javascript-operator-why-is-not-defined-not-treated-as-undefined/73752716?noredirect=1#comment130234367_73752716) @connexo Both examples include an attempt to access the non-existent property `y` on `w`.

Comment: That `.y` is only relevant to the question because you need it to even be able to use  `w?`. Neither does the working example secure against an `undefined` `y`, nor does the reference error have anything to do with it.